# Is there another way for this abstract class to derive from this generic type? Error CS0310

Tags: c#, generics

I have these pieces of code:

```
// The Singleton.cs file.
public abstract class Singleton<T> where T : class, new()
{
    private static T _instance;

    public static T Instance => _instance ?? (_instance = new T());
}
// The ScriptEvent.cs file.
public abstract class ScriptEvent : Singleton<ScriptEvent>
{
    public abstract void RaiseEvent(params object[] raiseParameters);

    public abstract void Subscribe(Delegate toSubscribe);

    public abstract void Unsubscribe(Delegate toUnsubscribe);

    public abstract Delegate[] GetSubscribers();
}
```

I would like for ScriptEvent to derive from Singleton since ScriptEvent has to be a singleton. This however gives me this error:

```
Error   CS0310  'ScriptEvent' must be a non-abstract type with a public parameterless constructor in order to use it as parameter 'T' in the generic type or method 'Singleton<T>
```

So far the only solution I can see is to directly implement the Singleton functionality directly into ScriptEvent, and while this would work, does feel quite unclean/unnecessary to me.

Is there a way I could solve this issue? I would prefer to keep ScriptEvent as Abstract, although as I am writing this I have realized I could also deabstract it and use virtual methods instead. That might however confuse future users of this code, since they might try to instantiate a ScriptEvent, which isn´t intended (hence the singletonization :P and abstraction). I also suppose that one other solution would be to make ScriptEvent generic, and have derived classes provide their own type, similar to how the Singleton works, but I would consider this quite unoptimal, since I would prefer to avoid as much possible confusion for derivers.

EDIT: I have found a (temporary?) solution to my problem.
I use the "deabstract" method. I made the class into a regular class, replaced all abstract methods with almost identical virtual ones, but added an empty static constructor to prevent instancing!
I would still however like an answer, as I am not quite satisfied with this solution.

Comment: Is there a reason you implement this as a templated singleton? Are you using DI? If so, why not just let DI handle the scope instead?

Comment: What do you expect to happen when you call `new T()`? You can't instantiate a ScriptEvent, of course, because it is abstract.

Comment: @JohnWu That's true! I want new T() to effectively "call new <derived type>" instead. Is that possible?

Comment: @Charleh I'm not sure I know what you mean by "DI". The reason I wanted to implement this as a templated ("generic"?) singleton was because I believe that might be a bit cleaner. Maybe that is incorrect.

Answer (score 1):

Remove the inheritance. Use a type constraint instead.

```
// The Singleton.cs file.
public abstract class Singleton<T> where T : ScriptEvent, new() //Type constraint
{
    private static T _instance;

    public static T Instance => _instance ?? (_instance = new T());
}

// The ScriptEvent.cs file.
public abstract class ScriptEvent  //No inheritance
{
    public abstract void RaiseEvent(params object[] raiseParameters);

    public abstract void Subscribe(Delegate toSubscribe);

    public abstract void Unsubscribe(Delegate toUnsubscribe);

    public abstract Delegate[] GetSubscribers();
}
```

Then to get an instance you'd use:

```
var instance = Singleton<DerivedType>.Instance;
```

Comment: I had not considered this approach, this was very helpful. I think however that I will use the approach where ScriptEvent itself is a singleton (cloning the functionality of Singleton into ScriptEvent) to simplify the code. After all, I don't think I need a separate class just for ScriptEvent. Thanks regardless, and it's definitely possible I might use this approach in the future!